# How to use a Xaml Polygon exported from InkScape, in a CombinedGeometry-tag in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In our project we use a ResourceDictionary to define all the icons in our application. They are defined mostly in the following way:

```
<PathGeometry
    x:Key="BellIconSm"
    presentationOptions:Freeze="True"
    Figures="m 20.941 16.048 c 0 0 -0.005 -0.008 -0.006 -0.012 l -0.352 -0.391 0"
    FillRule="NonZero" />
```

But sometimes we use the `<CombinedGeometry>` to combine 2 or more shapes.

I get the icon most of the times as a .svg-file, which I then open in InkScape and just do a Save As to Xaml format. Normally the exported Xaml file from InkScape can look like the following (truncated, i.e. only the beginning part is included):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file is NOT compatible with Silverlight-->
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Name="Layer_2_1_" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="71.6" Height="98">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas.Resources/>
    <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
    <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path13" Fill="#000000">
      <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M0.4 50c1.6 1.3 2.7 3.2-0.6c0.5-1.1-1.8-4.8 2.7-6.9c4.5-2.1 9.5 3 9.5 3s3.5-9 11.1-9.1  c8.2-0.1 12.1 7.2 12.1 7.2s6.5-5.8 11.7-2.6c4.6 2.8 2.1 8 3 9.2c0.8 1.2 2.8 0.9 3.4 0c0.5-0.9 1.3-10.8-3.5-14  c-6.4-4.3-13.4 1.5-13.4 1.5s-2.9-6.3-11.8-6.5c-8.8-0.2-13.1 6.4-13.1 6.4S10 34.8 4.2 37.8C-1.6 40.8-1.2 48.8 0.4 50z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
      </Path.Data>
    </Path>
.
.
.
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

..and I just copy the `<PathGeometry Figures="...>` part from the InkScape-exported Xaml to my `<PathGeometry>` or `<CombinedGeometry>` in my ResourceDictionary, and everything works fine.

Now for the first time, 2 rows with a `<Polygon>` tag was included in the InkScape-exported Xaml file which looks like the following (truncated, only the last part included):

```
.
.
.
    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path21" Fill="#000000">
      <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M53.4 15" FillRule="NonZero"/>
      </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Polygon xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Points="60.1,16.9 62.6,26.1 71.6,27.8 62.8,30.1 60.5,40.2 57.8,30.1 49,28.4 57.8,26.5 " Name="polygon23" FillRule="NonZero" Fill="#000000"/>
    <Polygon xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Points="40.7,0 44.5,13.9 58,16.4 44.8,19.8 41.4,35 37.3,19.8 24,17.3 37.3,14.5 " Name="polygon25" FillRule="NonZero" Fill="#000000"/>
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

My question is how I do to include them in my `<CombinedGeometry>` tag in my ResourceDictionary? From what I can see I can't use the `<Polygon>` tag directly, so my best shot was to do it in the following way (truncated, only the last part included:

```
<CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M53.4 15" FillRule="NonZero" />
        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
                        <PathFigure>
                            <PolyLineSegment Points="40.7,0 44.5,13.9 58,16.4 44.8,19.8 41.4,35 37.3,19.8 24,17.3 37.3,14.5 " />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
                        <PathFigure>
                            <PolyLineSegment Points="60.1,16.9 62.6,26.1 71.6,27.8 62.8,30.1 60.5,40.2 57.8,30.1 49,28.4 57.8,26.5 " />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
            </CombinedGeometry>
        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
    </CombinedGeometry>
</CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
```

But when running the application a part of the icon doesn't have the correct shape, so something is obviously missing. The icon should look like this:

[image: Correct icon]

but in the application it turns out like this:

[image: Incorrect icon]

So it's obviously the `<Polygon>`/`<PolyLineSegment>` tags that are wrong, or have missing parts. What could be possibly wrong here?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: How about `<PathFigure StartPoint="40.7,0" IsClosed="True">`?

Comment: As a note, instead of nested CombinedGeometries you may perhaps also use a GeometryGroup.

Comment: #Clemens So you thing that would change the way the icon is displayed? I use lots of nested CombinedGeometries for all our other icons in this ResourceDirectory. It's only this time when I had to use Polygons that things went wrong. I will try your other idea.

Comment: #Clemens I tried your suggestion, i.e. <PathFigure StartPoint="40.7,0" IsClosed="True"> and <PathFigure StartPoint="60.1,16.9" IsClosed="True"> for the Polygons, and you made my day! Huge huge thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `StartPoint` property of the PathFigures and close them by setting `IsClosed="True"`:

```
<CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
        <PathFigure StartPoint="40.7,0" IsClosed="True">
            <PolyLineSegment Points="44.5,13.9 58,16.4 44.8,19.8 41.4,35 37.3,19.8 24,17.3 37.3,14.5"/>
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
</CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
<CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
        <PathFigure StartPoint="60.1,16.9" IsClosed="True">
            <PolyLineSegment Points="62.6,26.1 71.6,27.8 62.8,30.1 60.5,40.2 57.8,30.1 49,28.4 57.8,26.5"/>
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
</CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
```

Comment: Yes, like I wrote in the comments field as a response to one of your comments, that's what I did, and the problem was solved. Big thanks once again!!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

As suggested by #Clemens in the Comments for the question, the issue was solved by adding

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="40.7,0" IsClosed="True">
```

and

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="60.1,16.9" IsClosed="True">
```

to the two polygons respectively.